# How to delete trigger character when using vscode api completion feature?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, triggers, vscode-extensions, completion

I'm creating a vscode extension that requires some custom completion for json files. Is it possible to not show the trigger character when using autocompletions.

Here is what I mean :

Let's say the trigger character is '.'
In your json file you type '.' which suggests you a list of items that I defined in the code.
When i press tab or enter, the normal behavior would be to display .item (item being the selected item when i pressed enter)
Is it possible to only have 'item' and remove the trigger character '.' ?

Here is my code so far :

```
context.subscriptions.push(languages.registerCompletionItemProvider (
            { language: 'json', scheme: 'file' },
            // 'json',
            {
                provideCompletionItems(document: TextDocument, position: Position, token: CancellationToken, context: CompletionContext) {
        
                let myitem = (text:string) => {
                    let item = new CompletionItem(text, CompletionItemKind.Text);
                    item.range = new Range(position, position);
                    return item;
                };

                const linePrefix = document.lineAt(position).text.substring(0, position.character);
                if (linePrefix.match(/name/g)) {
                    return [
                        myitem('log'),
                        myitem('warn'),
                        myitem('error'),
                        ];
                } else {
                    return undefined;
                }
            }
            },
            '?' // trigger
        ));
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66407855/836330 - although a modified version of that isn't working for me yet,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general the trigger characters would be removed automatically but I believe because your trigger character `?` is a non-word character (at least in `json` files) that vscode returns `undefined` when trying to get the `wordRangeAtPosition(position)` and so does not replace the trigger character.

So you will have to take matters into your hands.  One way is to get the `wordRangeAtPosition()` using a custom regex that includes `?`.  And then use that range in the `CompletionItem.range`.

After playing around unsuccessfully trying to set the `range` to a value that would include and thus replace that `?` like the link in my comment above, I found success with a different method.  Thanks to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/75237

Try adding this to your `CompletionItems`:

```js
let myitem = (text) => {
    let item = new vscode.CompletionItem(text, vscode.CompletionItemKind.Text);
    // item.range = new vscode.Range(position, position);

    const rangeToRemove = new vscode.Range(position.line, position.character-1, position.line, position.character);
    item.additionalTextEdits = [vscode.TextEdit.delete(rangeToRemove)];

    return item;
};
```

In my testing with the code above you do not need the following line since you will be using the default:

```js
item.range = new Range(position, position);
```

{I showed the non-typescript version with `vscode.` added to the calls for general use.]

Comment: Thanks ! Addind the two lines to my `CompletionItems` seems to do the work just fine. However, if I delete the item.range line as you suggest, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I  tried it again and I do not need the `item.range` line.  I edited the answer to show what I am using to create `myItem`.